# Hysteresis threshold changed when connecting a transistor to the output of a comparator LM393,

Tags: transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRxkGi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi all, I have built an inverting comparator with hystersis using LM393. First I calculated \$R1,R2,R3\,R4_{pull-up}\$ and got the exact upper and lower hysteresis threshold \$V_{TH}=1.8V\$ and \$V_{TL}=1.39V\$. However, when I connect a transistor \$Q1\$ (I want to use it as a switch, when its ON, let as much as possible current flow through the load \$R6=20\Omega\$), the upper hysteresis threshold has decreased to  \$V_{TH}=1.47V\$ and \$V_{TL}\$ didn't change.

Here are my questions:

1. I thought I need to take \$R5,R6\$ into hysteresis calculation. But how? The load resistance \$R6=20\Omega\$ cannot change.
2. How to make \$Q1\$ saturate when it is ON? I have iterated \$R5\$ with many different values from \$100\Omega\$ to \$10k\Omega\$ but cannot make B-C junction forward bias. My goal is to get maximum current flow through the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsaBII.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that since transistor inverts output, you use (Vin-) for positive (+) feedback.

LM393 open collector NPN has an equivalent ESR.

**Saturation Voltage** Vout 700 mV max at I SINK ≤4 mA,

- thus ESR= 700mV/4mA = 175Ω max   "ESR or Rce = Vce(sat)/If."
- if using a BJT switch you correctly choose Rb/Rc=10 but since it is internal to IC equivalent Rce, R5 can be 0 Ω and Q1 must be PNP.

Right now with NPN your effective Rb/Rc = R4/R6  and is too high thus hysteresis problems.

Answer (score 3):

You made R5 (200 ohms) too low.

The LM393 has an open collector output which can only pull the output **low**. So that's why R4 is needed. R4 is the **only** component pulling the output of the LM393 high.

Now imagine that the LM393 does not pull the output low, then its output is open, it cannot pull the voltage up (since it is an open collector of an NPN transistor). There's only R4 pulling the voltage up.

You're also loading the output of the LM393 with R5 (200 ohms) and an NPN Base-Emitter junction. There will be around 0.7 V across that Base-Emitter junction. That 200 ohm will not drop much voltage so the LM393's output will be slightly above 0.7 V, maybe it will reach 1 V.

For the hysteresis levels you calculated the LM393's output must be 5 V (supply voltage). This will not happen until you increase the value of R5.

Also you do not need such a low base resistor for Q1 as Q1 has plenty of current gain. Increase R5 to around 4.7 kohm, that will still not give you the right upper threshold level but will be much closer. You might also need to lower R4 to 1 kohm and then you should be quite close.

A simpler solution was suggested by Trevor: throw out R4 and Q1 and replace these with an NMOS.

If you don't like NMOSFETs you could add a 2nd NPN to make a Darlington type configuration:

[image: schematic]

This makes the current through R5 so small that it barely influences the levels at V1.

Comment: R5 (200) is actually greater the Rce. the real problem was R4 pullup.

Answer (score 1):

LM393 is an open collector part, so your base current is actually R4 AND R5. You would be better either using a mosfet instead of a BJT like so

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feIwdm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Note that this inverts the output signal (on becomes off and reverse) which might be inconvenient. Unfortunately this cannot be easily solved by swapping the + and - inputs of the LM393 as that would also break the positive feedback needed for the hysteresis.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yup not only that but the PNP it will never turn off.. that's what happens when you rush an answer before you run of of the door. sigh